# Unable to Access Terra-Master F4 NAS with Full HDD's

Tags: network-attached-storage

I have a TerraMaster F4 NAS in a RAID 1 configuration. The drives ended up filling up (only 20.0 K free according to a mapped drive's info), and now I can't access any data on them.

At this point I'm perfectly content just to get in there and start deleting some files, however nothing I do seems to work.

1. Mapped drives in Windows 10 won't connect.
2. Shared folders (using the NAS IP) in Windows 10 also won't connect.
3. File mounts in Linux (Debian 9) will initially connect and allow me to view the file lists, however attempting to delete ultimately results in an I/O error.
4. SSH is rejected on port 22.

I have reached out to TM support, however I was hoping someone here might be able to provide additional solutions while I'm waiting.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Isn't there a web interface you can connect to it with and delete files from there?

Comment: The web interface isn't functioning either, which I believe is also a result of the HDD's being full.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately bought an external HDD case, connected it, and remounted the drive using mdadm so that I could delete files and copy the drive. From my research it appears that every server handles the disk full scenario differently, so if you’re looking at this for different hardware you may not need to go this route.